# SQL Statement with Join - missing record ... (simple noob request)

Tags: mysql, sql

this is a noob-question, I know.
I have 2 tables:

[image: DB Design]

The data looks like this ...

**products_services:**

[image]

**product_service_categories:**

[image]

My SQL-Statement looks like this:

```
SELECT product_service_id, product_service_name, product_service_category_name
FROM products_services
JOIN product_service_categories ON
products_services.product_service_category_id = product_service_categories.product_service_category_id
WHERE products_services.company_id = '7'
ORDER BY product_service_category_name, product_service_name
```

The result looks like this:

[image: SQL result]

I am missing the entry for "ID 2 - Ernährungsberatung". The entry is missing because its "product_service_category_id" is "0".

Please help me with the correct SQL-Statement to get this record too.

Thank you!

Comment: Question doesn't make sense.  If you want id 2, why are you filtering on company id?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My screenshots werde not correct. There was an sample-entry missing on Screenshot for table product_services with "company_id =7" and "product_service_category_id = 0". But Dudu's answer did the thing ... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`
`JOIN` returns only matching rows.
`LEFT JOIN` returns all rows from the left table with possible matches from the right table.

Comment: I'm sorry. I saw, that my screenshot for the table "products_services" was wrong and the entry with "company_id =7" and "product_service_category_id = 0" is missing. 
But ... many thanks for your answer! It is working with "LEFT JOIN"!!! :-)
Have a nice day!

Comment: Just implemented it in my application. It is working :-) :-) :-) Thanks